# Will vmware power off reset vm file?

Tags: vmware

I have a question.  Will vmware power off reset vmware file?

I would like to move my *.sql file from my windows to vmware linux.  I heard if you want to be able to import file to vmware you must set the sharing folder in vmware file and be able to add file and folder in folder sharing session.

In order to do so I heard you have to power off the vmware file, the thing is if you power off the vmware file will the current session disappeared and must be start over from the beginning?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "power off the vmware file"? What do you mean by "current session"? Have you tried to do your own research, for example to experiment with a throwaway VM?

Comment: I do not have a new iso or vmware and it takes forever to download one.  Can you not just advice me if power off = reset the whole vmware current session or power off != reset the whole vmware session?  I usually save the current session and afraid of it being deleted since I do not want to start over.

Comment: You're using unusual terms and I don't understand what you mean, so I asked for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, I think you are asking:

> If I "*power off*" a virtual machine, will I loose all of it's state?

To which the answer is: yes - just like if you were to "*power off*" a PC.

Don't think of it as a "*VMware File*", but more as a "*Virtual Machine*" that has:

- Configuration (stored in `*.vmx` files)
- A hard disk (stored in `*.vmdk` files)
- RAM (stored in the physical machine's RAM, and is thus [volatile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_memory))

It is possible to save the VM's state and resume later, but when the VM is in this state there will be restrictions on what changes can be made to its configuration.

---

Bear in mind that there are plenty of other ways to get files off a VM aside from using VMware's "*Shared Folders*" feature. For example Windows file sharing, passing a USB memory stick to the VM, etc...

And why can't you shutdown the VM? If you really can't afford to turn it off, then you are in dangerous waters - back up any important / volatile data ASAP.

I don't believe that VMware is making your situation special, aside from the fact that you've relied on the "*save state*" feature far too heavily - which is akin to keeping a PC turned on *all the time*, and a power outage or crash being a critical situation.